# How to do a function with a select option value

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with two input select, the second input only can be enable if the first one was selected. And I'm having doubts. I tried to do an onclick event, but failed. Can someone help me? (sorry for the broken english)

Comment: can you post the code you have so far

Comment: Use an `onchange` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [dependsOn](http://dstreet.github.io/dependsOn/) if you are willing to use jQuery. It does most of the heavy lifting for you.